# Is there a terminal supporting embeded graph under linux?

Tags: linux, terminal, shell, console, ipython

everyone. I want to know if there is a graphic terminal which support viewing images inline. The ipython qtconsole is very cool because it has the '%matplotlib inline' magic. But  I'd like to use shell commands in such a terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There have been efforts for such kind of terminal emulator, but to my knowledge none of them are stable (or still being actively developed). Search for:

- Terminology terminal emulator: http://www.enlightenment.org/p.php?p=about/terminology
- Exterminate terminal emulator: https://github.com/substack/exterminate

There are probably more of these projects, but none of them seem really viable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [qtconsole](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/qtconsole.html) with iPython.